# How to get contents of a given "path" using 'ls -l' command and Python

Tags: python, subprocess, ls

I am using python and i want to get listing of all of the files /directories (not nested) at a given path. Meaning i need exact equivalent out put of "ls -l" command using python.

For e.g. at path /opt/test/ ls -l out put is shown below.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user  qa-others  16715 Jan 16 13:38 file_2001161337
-rw-r--r--  1 user  qa-others  16715 Jan 16 13:46 file_2001161346
-rw-r--r--  1 user  qa-others  16715 Jan 16 13:54 file_2001161353
```

My python code is shown below.

```
print(subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l']))
```

How can i pass the path value i.e. "/opt/temp" and get the same put of "ls -l" as shown above?

Comment: `print(subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l', '/opt/temp']))`?

Comment: Be careful, sir, the road is treacherous. There be dragons out there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead

Answer (score 0):

You are far, far better off using [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.listdir), which essentially exactly what you want.

You can also use [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.scandir) if you need other information about these folders, though you'll need to filter to ensure you're only picking up folders:

```
[e for e in os.scandir() if e.isdir]
```

Each of these functions takes a path argument if you want to explicitly specify it, otherwise they run on the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pathlib.Path()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) for this (Python >=3.4):

```py
from pathlib import Path

source = Path('/opt/temp')

# Get all children
content = source.glob('*')
```

By default this will return an iterator of `pathlib.Path` objects (cast iterator to list if you need a visual check).
Then you can programmatically access file attributes using [`pahtlib.Path.stat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.stat).